# PC not detecting Samsung Galaxy Light SGH-T399

Tags: samsung, usb-connection-mode

I just bought a used Samsung Galaxy Light SGH-T399N. When i connect it to PC, it is not detecting my cell phone, even after installing the Samsung mobile devices driver the window shows usb icon in the notification area of taskbar but nothing appears in My Computer. I also tried kies 2, kies 3 and smart touch but neither of them are supporting my device. I tried it on both windows 7 and windows 8.1.

Comment: Check the window device manager to see if it found your device. if not add new device

Comment: @cmos the problem was resolved after resetting the device.